# Images of contour under the mapping $w=1+\sin(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider the strip $S:=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:0<\text{Re}(z)<5\pi/4,\text{Im}(z)=0\}$
What function $w=1+\sin(z)$ maps strip into?
How should I approach it? Should I parametrize lines and go from there? But, I don't get how to parametrize a line from infinity to zero. Any help?

Comment: $S$ is a part of real axis then it's image is $1+\sin$ curve as we see in real case.

Comment: Any $z\in S$ is real.  So therefore $w$ must also be real.  And since the sine function is bounded in $\mathbb{R}$, they leaves you in a good place to determine the mapping...